# Struts 2 action class not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am using struts2 for developing a web application.
I have include the required jars for struts2 but when it is going to call the struts action class it is throwing 404 error.
There is no error on console and browser does not showing .action extension whitch it shows when struts.xml call an action class.
I am using `jdk 1.6` and `struts 2.0`.
Am I missing any jar who is responsible for all this.

In jsp I am simply calling the function from
 
`<s:form action = "Mergexmlaction" method = "post"/>`

Here is my struts.xml and web.xml

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts> 
  <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="6000000000" /> 

  <package name="default" namespace="/jsp" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="Mergexmlaction" class="com.hm.merge.mergeaction.Mergexmlaction">
      <result name="success" >/jsp/Result.jsp</result>
      <result name="error" >/jsp/Browse_multiplexmlfiles.jsp</result> 
      <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="maximumSize">600000000</param> 
      </interceptor-ref> 
    </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="xml_file_merging" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"> 
  <display-name>xml_file_merging</display-name>
  <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>jsp/Browse_multiplexmlfiles.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What about the web.xml? Did you set the struts dispatcher there?

Comment: lots of information needed? about your web.xml, what URL you hitting when you getting this information, without which impossible to answer.

Comment: I've added my struts and web.xml file....<br/>
In jsp I am simply calling the function from s:form

Comment: its only giving 404 or any other error also. And are you getting error when you starting your application or when you hitting any specific URL?

Comment: This is the problem... It is not giving any error on console jus on browser. when I start application first page displayed perfectly but when I submit the request as I described.. <s:form> then I am getting this error....

Comment: can you show the URL is is coming on the browser when you submitting the page?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/xml_file_merging/Mergexmlaction

point to note there is nothing like Mergexmlaction.action

Comment: There is a silly mistake I've done.... I've given the name to my struts.xml as Struts.xml.... Now its working fine thanks to all I learned so much by your answers and will remind these things for future... Thanks a tone...:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues.

```
<package name="default" namespace="/jsp" extends="struts-default">
```

**1)** I'd recommend *against* having a namespace of "jsp", it doesn't make any sense. Namespaces should be something meaningful to the application and/or user.

```
  <action name="Mergexmlaction" class="com.hm.merge.mergeaction.Mergexmlaction">
```

**2)** Don't name an action with "action", there will either be a `.action` extension, or no extension at all. Either way, there's no reason to duplicate "action" in the first case, and no reason to use "action" if there's no extension. Just "mergexml", "mergeXml", etc.

```
    <result name="success" >/jsp/Result.jsp</result>
```

**3)** I recommend putting your JSP pages under `WEB-INF` to avoid direct client access.

```
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
```

**4)** Once you declare *any* interceptors, you must declare *all* interceptors. This action has only a single interceptor running. It's *possible* this is okay, but it's almost never the right thing to do.

```
<welcome-file>jsp/Browse_multiplexmlfiles.jsp</welcome-file>
```

**5)** And this is the ultimate issue, depending on how you're accessing the application. You show the welcome file as being a JSP page, which is presumably using S2 tags. This won't work: the tags depend on their being a complete S2 request, a value stack, etc.

All access to an S2 app should take place through an S2 action, *not* a JSP. If you look at the rendered HTML for the directly-accessed JSP you'll see neither namespace nor action extension rendered.

Comment: Thanks for reply Dave, but my welcome page is running fine..  The issue is when I am calling any action then its not running and even it is not showing any action extension.

Comment: There is a silly mistake I've done....   I've given the name to my struts.xml as Struts.xml....   Now its working fine thanks to all I learned so much by your answers and will remind these things for future...  Thanks a tone...:)

Answer (score 1):

an error 404 is a bad link. means you just are calling a link that doesnt exist. Check your mapping in your struts config file and make sure you use the correct url.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace attribute of package element is optional and if it is not present, the default value "/" is assumed. If the namespace attribute has a non-default value, the namespace must be added to the URI that invokes the actions in the package.

For example, the URI for invoking an action in a package with a default namespace is this:

/context/actionName

To invoke an action in a package with a non-default namespace, you need this URI:

/context/namespace/actionName

Comment: There is a silly mistake I've done.... I've given the name to my struts.xml as Struts.xml.... Now its working fine thanks to all I learned so much by your answers and will remind these things for future... Thanks a tone...:)