# Why we need to use 'params' interceptor while using 'timer' interceptor in struts2 framework?

Tags: java, struts2

I am learning Struts2 framework and came across this thing.

When I am not specifying interceptor in struts.xml file then all the parameter are passing to Action class but when I am specifying `timer` interceptor in struts.xml file then I have to specify the `params` interceptor too, in order to retrieve parameters in Action class.

Any idea why it is like this?

Comment: Because by *specifying 'timer' interceptor* you're not including other interceptors. You should use some stack and add interceptor to it.

Comment: Didn't know that reason is so simple. Thanks :)

Comment: Point 4 in http://stackoverflow.com/a/9213477/438992: If you declare *any* interceptors for an action you must declare *all* interceptors (although it can be with a set of interceptors).